# Why does my loop ignore and add NULL to every second item in the database?

Tags: php, yii

I've inherited code from an old developer that was commented out and I've re-implemented it. A problem I've encountered is that the second item I'm putting in is registering the value as NULL.

The first two snippets of code are what I'm guessing is causing the issue for adding NULL for every second item being inserted into the database.

I have these three functions in the user model:

```
public function getDynamicVaribles() {
    $string = null;
    foreach ($this->userVariables as $var) {
        $string .= $var->userTypeVariables->name . '=' . $var->value . "<br />";
    }
    return $string;
}

public function getDynamicVaribleValue($varName) {
    foreach ($this->userVariables as $var) {
        if ($var->userTypeVariables->name == $varName) {
            return $var->value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public function getDynamicVarible($varName) {
    foreach ($this->userVariables as $userVariable) {
        if ($userVariable->userTypeVariables->name == $varName) {
            return $userVariable;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I'm calling it like so in the _form view:

```
<?php
    $varform = new DynamicForm();
    $varform->attributes = $user->getDynamicFormConfig();
    $varform->model_name = 'user';
    echo $varform->run();
?>
```

And the function calling it in the my controller

```
foreach ($user->type->userTypeVariables as $userTypeVar) {

    // Get fields for slide_varibles
    // load Model here...

    $slide_varible = $user->getDynamicVarible($userTypeVar->name);
    // if ($slide_varible == null) {
    //     $slide_varible = new UserVariables;
    // }
    $slide_varible = new UserVariables;
    $slide_varible->user_id = $user->id;
    $slide_varible->value = 
        $_POST['user' . '_' . str_replace(' ', '_', $userTypeVar->name)];
    $slide_varible->user_type_variables_id = $userTypeVar->id;

    $slide_varible->save(false);
}
```

My attributes in the components (can probably be ignored):

```
foreach ($this->attributes as $attr) {
    $attr['formname'] = $this->model_name . '_' . $attr['name'];
    $attr['htmlOptions'] = 
        array('class' => 'span5', 'placeholder' => $attr['name']);
    $attr['htmlOptions']['class'] .= ' form-control';

    if ($attr['required'] === 1){
        $attr['requiredfields'] = array('required' => true);
    }else{
        $attr['requiredfields'] = '';
    }
    // Per type input            
    // 'type'=>'text|radio|textarea|select'


    if ($attr['type'] == 'text') {
        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo CHtml::label($attr['name'], $attr['formname'], 
                $attr['requiredfields']);
        echo CHtml::textField($attr['formname'], $attr['value'], 
                $attr['htmlOptions']);
        echo '</div>';
    } 
    elseif ($attr['type'] == 'radio') {
        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo CHtml::label($attr['name'], $attr['formname'],
                $attr['requiredfields']);
        echo CHtml::radioButton($attr['formname'],
                $attr['requiredfields']);
        echo '</div>';
    } 
    elseif ($attr['type'] == 'textarea') {
        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo CHtml::label($attr['name'], $attr['formname'],
                $attr['requiredfields']);
        echo CHtml::textArea($attr['formname'], $attr['value'], 
                $attr['htmlOptions']);
        echo '</div>';
    } 
    elseif ($attr['type'] == 'select') {
        $items = explode(',', $attr['options']);

        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo CHtml::label($attr['name'], $attr['formname'],
                $attr['requiredfields']);
        echo CHtml::dropDownList($attr['formname'], $attr['value'], 
                array($items));
        echo '</div>';

    } 
    elseif ($attr['type'] == 'boolean') {
        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo CHtml::label($attr['name'], $attr['formname'],
                $attr['requiredfields']);
        echo CHtml::radioButtonList($attr['formname'], $attr['value'], 
                array('No' => 0, 'Yes' => 1));
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

The issue that I've encountered is that regardless of the dynamic form field type / or the input being put into this form, it's just adding NULL to the value field.

EDIT. The reason why the value was not being inserted is due to the full stop character "." was causing the database entry to go in as NULL.

Comment: This question has been asked two days ago. Have you been able to solve it? My initial impression leads me to believe that something might be wrong here: `$_POST['user' . '_' . str_replace(' ', '_', $userTypeVar->name)];`

Comment: Hi, the issue has turned out to be that the full stop we were using in the input was preventing it being inserted into the database. I'm still not entirely sure what is causing that

Comment: Full stop, as in `.`?

Comment: Yep, for example our text field said 4.30pm , that was causing the prevention of the field to the database.  I've not had a look at it but I had just assumed it was every second field.

Comment: Hmm.. So it seems that this question cannot be answred now because the code provided here does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is best to close it or to mark it as answered.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure either. My suggestion though is to answer it on your own, then mark that answer as an accepted so as to 'close' this thread. You never know, someone might see your question and deduce something based on your answer. That happened to me many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing and pure luck, I found out that the reason why the value was not posting to the database and resulting in a NULL Value, was the full stop character ".". Every other character I've tested results in the correct insert to the database.

As of posting I've not done any looking into why this is happening, but will update post if successful.